# How do I use jest in this application?

Tags: javascript, json, jestjs

I'm new to Jest and have learnt about it's few features like `expect()`, `toBe()` etc. 
I have an online pizza ordering application created using vanilla javascript. I have stored the pizza item details in a json file and I'm fetching these details in one javascript file and accordingly rendering them to the UI. I have a few buttons like "Add to Cart", "Order", "Remove from Cart" etc which are working fine. 

Now, I want to test my application using jest. I have done the Jest setup already and created one file - **store.jest.js**

```
const store = require("./store");
test("testing app js", () => {
  console.log("Hello tests world");
});
```

**store.js**

```
document.onload = (function runOnLoad() {
  fetch("./data.json")
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const allItemContainer = document.getElementById("all-items");
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

      data.pizza.forEach((item) => {
        let container = document.createElement("div");
        //container will contain <div class='shop-item'>
        container.classList.add("shop-item");
        container.id = item.id; //will add an id to the current div equal to the ID given in the json file
        let textHeading = document.createElement("span");
        textHeading.classList.add("shop-item-title");
        textHeading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name));
        //textHeading contains <span class="shop-item-title">Tandoori Pizza</span>

        let images = document.createElement("img");
        images.classList.add("shop-item-image");
        images.src = item.image;
        //images contains <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/pizza.png">

        let innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
        innerDiv.classList.add("shop-item-details");
        //innerDiv contains <div class="shop-item-details"

        let price = document.createElement("span");
        price.classList.add("shop-item-price");
        //<span class="shop-item-price">Rs.200</span>
        price.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.price));

        //Creating <div class="shop-item-sizes"> for taking sizes for radio buttons
        let sizesRadio = document.createElement("div");
        sizesRadio.classList.add("shop-item-sizes");

        for (size in item.sizes) {
          //console.log(size); //small, medium, large
          //console.log(Object.keys(item.sizes)); - shows small, medium, large
          //console.log(item); - will contain entire details of one pizza item
          let sizesTemp = Object.keys(item.sizes);
          let newRadio = document.createElement("input");
          newRadio.type = "radio";
          newRadio.value = item.sizes[size]; //value will be stored as price of small, medium, large - 100, 200, 300
          //console.log(newRadio.value);
          newRadio.name = "sizes";
          let label = document.createElement("label");
          label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(size));
          sizesRadio.appendChild(newRadio);
          sizesRadio.appendChild(label);
          innerDiv.appendChild(sizesRadio);
        }

        let butt = document.createElement("button");
        butt.classList.add("btn", "btn-primary", "shop-item-button");
        butt.innerText = "ADD TO CART";
        butt.onclick = addToCartClicked;

        innerDiv.appendChild(price);
        // innerDiv.appendChild(butt2);
        innerDiv.appendChild(butt);
        // innerDiv.appendChild(butt1);

        container.appendChild(textHeading);
        container.appendChild(images);
        container.appendChild(innerDiv);
        fragment.appendChild(container);
        allItemContainer.appendChild(fragment);
      });
    });
```

ERROR:-

```
Test suite failed to run
    ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

I'm not sure why am I getting this failed test case. The site is working properly. Also, could someone tell me what type of test cases can I add in `store.test.js` with their snippets.

Comment: Use `jest-fetch-mock` to mock the reponse you expect, the file you wanting. https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock

Comment: @ChanceSmith I followed the steps mentioned in the link but couldn't make it work. It says Jest: command not found

Comment: You might try installing jest globally `npm install -g jest`